# What information does B&N collect about my Nook Usage?

Tags: nook

My wife and I both have nooks attached to the same account.  I have noticed that the when I open up a book that I have been reading on her Nook(usually because I let my battery go dead) that it knows what page I was on, with in a few minutes.

This got me thinking that if they are tracking where I am at in the book ***what other usage information are they collecting?***

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Barnes & Noble Mobile Privacy Supplement](http://www.barnesandnoble.com/mobile/legal.asp?view=fullpolicy) addresses the following questions as they relate to Devices and Retail Apps:

> 1. What personal information do we collect?
> 2. How do we collect personal information?
> 3. How do we use personal information?
> 4. With whom do we share personal information?
> 5. What else about Barnes & Noble’s Mobile Privacy Supplement would I want to know?

In section 2b, the information automatically collected is detailed:

> (b) Information automatically collected
>
> When you use a Device or Retail App, we may automatically collect
>   information from your Device or Retail App when it is connected to the
>   Internet. For example, we may receive and collect information
>   concerning your Device or Retail App registration, settings, usage,
>   firmware version, signal strength, search queries, network
>   interaction, the name of the network from which you access the
>   Internet, the Internet Protocol address of the device you are using,
>   downloads, sideloaded content, configuration, service, or information
>   related to any malfunction of the Device or Retail App. In addition,
>   when your Device or Retail App connects to wireless networks operated
>   by Barnes & Noble (e.g., within Barnes & Noble locations) we may
>   collect information concerning your location when it makes such a
>   connection.

Comment: Especially collecting information about the side-loaded content would for me be a reason not to use a Nook.

Comment: I was surprised by that too. Too much snooping for my liking :)